# el capitan or macOS sierra: move window to right hand desktop

Tags: macos, applescript, ui-automation, macos-sierra

With osascript/applescript or bash, how can one move the currently focussed/foregrounded window to the desktop on the right?

When doing this manually by hand, I first click and hold mouse on the title bar of a window, then press Control-2 (2 means second desktop)

But I want to automate this.